# How to compute the accumulative sum of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have this list of tuples and want to make a new list, with the accumulative sum of the previous list indexes:

```
List = [(1.0, 1.0), (3.0, 3.0), (5.0, 5.0)]

newList = [(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 4.0), (9.0, 9.0)]
```

I'm using:

```
l1 = []
for j in l: #already a given list
    result = tuple(map(sum, zip(j, j+1)))
    #or
    result = (map(operator.add, j, j+1,))
    l1.append(result)
```

both cases (`zip` and `operator`) returns

> "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple "

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.accumulate([1, 3, 5])
<itertools.accumulate object at 0x7f90cf33b188>
>>> list(_)
[1, 4, 9]
```

It accepts an optional `func` which is used to do addition:

```
>>> lst = [(1.0, 1.0), (3.0, 3.0), (5.0, 5.0)]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(lst, lambda a, b: tuple(map(sum, zip(a, b)))))
[(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 4.0), (9.0, 9.0)]
```

---

`itertools.accumulate` is introduced in Python 3.2. If you use lower version, use the following `accumulate` (came from the function documentation):

```
import operator
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        total = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: I need this for python 2.7. Itertools accumulate seems to work only in 3.x

Comment: @verto, Your question is tagged with [tag:python-3.x].

Comment: @verto, I added the function `accumulate` for you.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, could solve with this piece of code:

```
    result1=0
    result2=0
    l1=[]
    for k, v in l:
        result1+=k
        result2+=v
        l1.append((result1, result2))
```

Many thanks for the help! =)